# Why array.filter does not working properly with redux toolkit?

Tags: reactjs, arrays, filter, redux-toolkit

I try to `dispatch` delete `action` from array with `filter` method. Instead of deleting it returns array with some `proxy` stuff which I do not understand

This is my array

```
const initialState = [
  {
    likes: 112,
    title: "Add tags for solutions",
    details: "Easier to search for solutions based in soecific stack.",
    category: "Enhancement",
    commentCount: 2,
  },
  {
    likes: 99,
    title: "Add a dark theme option",
    details:
      "It would help people with light sensitivities and who prefer dark mode.",
    category: "Feature",
    commentCount: 2,
  },
];
```

and my reducer

```
delete(state, action) {
      state = state.filter(feedback => feedback.title !== action.payload);
      console.log(state); 
    }
```

and here I dispatch

```
const { title } = useParams();

function handleDelete() {
    dispatch(feedbackActions.delete(title));
    navigate("/");
  }
```

Comment: is the payload contain the title ?

Comment: @mercury nope. payloed came from link. I take it by useParams

Comment: Inside `Delete`, what does `state` look like before you overwrite it with filter? What does your reducer look like?

Comment: @WesleyLeMahieu if I got you correct, I log state inside delete before filter and it shown like proxy array thing with length 1

Answer (score 0):

What does you reducer look like? Giving it a delete case then passing delete as the dispatch type should do the trick.

```
const reducerFunc = (state, action) => {
        switch (action.type) {
            case "DELETE":
                return state.filter(feedback => feedback.title !== action.payload);
            default:
                return state
}
```